# Javascript regex to get the first term on the left side of a given sign?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

```
str = "Is toffee=sweet?"
```

Now I want to extract the first term on the left side of `=` which will be `toffee`.

So I do this

```
str.split("=")[0].split(" ").splice(-1,1)[0]
```

I get `toffee`

But if the string is like this

```
str = "Is toffee   =sweet?"
```

I get `empty string`

Is there any regex that I can use such that the first word on the left side of `=` irrespective of how many spaces are there is always caught?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split by `\s*=\s*`, to ensure the spaces around the `=` get consumed:

```js
const str = "Is toffee   =sweet?"
console.log(str.split(/ *= */)[0].split(" ").splice(-1,1)[0]);
```

I think `match` would be clearer, though, rather than splitting and splicing:

```js
const str = "Is toffee   =sweet?"
const match = str.match(/\w+(?= *=)/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

`\w+(?= *=)` matches one or more word characters which are followed by zero or more spaces and an `=`.

Comment: @Thanks! Can you post how the regex would change if I wanted the first word on right side of `=`?

Comment: If you want both, match `(\w+) *= *(\w+)`. Before part will be in first capture group, after part will be in second capture group.